# how to assess previous row values for current row iteratively in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to reduce by 1 and assign the last row of column B to the current row until I reach 0 or a non-null row.

| col_a | col_b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | null |
| 4 | null |
| 5 | null |
| 6 | null |
| 7 | 6 |
| 8 | null |
| 9 | null |

Here's what I'm hoping to get.

| col_a | col_b |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | null |
| Cell 2 | 3 |
| Cell 3 | 2 |
| Cell 4 | 1 |
| Cell 5 | 0 |
| Cell 6 | null |
| Cell 7 | 6 |
| Cell 8 | 5 |
| Cell 9 | 4 |

My code so far

```
data = [(1, None), (2, 3), (3, None), (4, None), (5, None), (6, None), (7, 6), (8, None), (9, None)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["col_a", "col_b"])

window_spec = Window.orderBy("col_a")

df = df.withColumn('col_b', 
              when(
                  (F.col('col_b').isNull()) & (F.lag(F.col('col_b')).over(window_spec) != 0),
                  (F.lag(F.col('col_b')).over(window_spec) - 1)
                  ).otherwise(F.col('col_b'))
             )

df.show()
```

My code only gets the last value that is currently present, and not those recently assigned. How do I get around this.

I know I can collect this column, process it, and add it back to the df but this is currently too computationally expensive for me since the dataset is very large.

Comment: does your data have grouping column(s) and ordering column(s)?

Comment: it only has dates, which I believe I can use for ordering.

Comment: so, you have a very large dataset with no grouping column? i have found a way to get the required output but it uses multiple windows. this might result in OOM errors.

Comment: The dataset consist of ids, dates, that can be used to group it. if we create a partition with the ids and date, the window will look like the example given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see following example that can help. note that i've created separate column for each calculation, but you can merge a few to make it concise.

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
import sys

wSpec = wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('c1')

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('id', func.lit('dummy_id')). \
    withColumn('reptval',
               func.last('c2', ignorenulls=True).over(wSpec.rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))
               ). \
    withColumn('changeflag',
               func.coalesce(func.col('reptval') != func.lag('reptval').over(wSpec), func.lit(True)).cast('int')
               ). \
    withColumn('cflag_csum',
               func.sum('changeflag').over(wSpec.rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))
               ). \
    withColumn('rn',
               func.row_number().over(wd.partitionBy('id', 'cflag_csum').orderBy('c1')) - 1
               ). \
    withColumn('c_interim', func.col('reptval') - func.col('rn')). \
    withColumn('c_fnl',
               func.when(func.col('c_interim') < 0, func.lit(None)).
               otherwise(func.col('c_interim'))
               ). \
    show()

# +---+----+--------+-------+----------+----------+---+---------+-----+
# | c1|  c2|      id|reptval|changeflag|cflag_csum| rn|c_interim|c_fnl|
# +---+----+--------+-------+----------+----------+---+---------+-----+
# |  1|null|dummy_id|   null|         1|         1|  0|     null| null|
# |  2|   3|dummy_id|      3|         1|         2|  0|        3|    3|
# |  3|null|dummy_id|      3|         0|         2|  1|        2|    2|
# |  4|null|dummy_id|      3|         0|         2|  2|        1|    1|
# |  5|null|dummy_id|      3|         0|         2|  3|        0|    0|
# |  6|null|dummy_id|      3|         0|         2|  4|       -1| null|
# |  7|   6|dummy_id|      6|         1|         3|  0|        6|    6|
# |  8|null|dummy_id|      6|         0|         3|  1|        5|    5|
# |  9|null|dummy_id|      6|         0|         3|  2|        4|    4|
# +---+----+--------+-------+----------+----------+---+---------+-----+
```

- `reptval` field repeats the column value till the non-null value.
- `changeflag` flags the row where a change in value (w.r.t prev row) occurs
- `cflag_csum` field is the cumulative sum of the change flag. this is done to create partitions
- `rn` is the row number (starting 0) for each `cflag_csum` partition. please add the actual partition columns as well within the `partitionBy`.
- then, all that's needed is to subtract the repeated values with the generated row number

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function row_number(), and subtract that (-1 because it starts at 1) instead of subtracting 1 from the previous row. However, for this to work you need to partition your window. To get the grouping, add a column with a cumulative sum, that increases when there's a non-null value in col_b (you can find other stackoverflow questions that show how to do a cumulative sum). Hope this helps.